# Can I substitute letters for long expressions in 5x5 matrix for Jordan decomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, jordan-normal-form, mathematica

I have a 5x5 matrix with long expressions, containing 15 variables. In Mathematica, taking Jordan decomposition of the original matrix makes no progress after one day. If I substitute 25 letters A-Z for each expression and substitute the original expressions in the matrices with eigenvalues and eigenvectors, is this correct?

Comment: There are a variety of ways to deal with expression overflow.... one is to, somewhat randomly, pick numerical values for your 15 variables, try the calculation over and over with actual numbers. If there is any pattern in the characteristic polynomial, or size of the Jordan blocks, it should show up

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange.  Your idea won't work for mathematical reasons: The characteristic polynomial of the matrix has degree 5 and its roots cannot be expressed in terms of radicals. Thus one cannot write down the eigenvalues in terms of the entries of the matrix.

Comment: @WillJagy I have to express eigenvalue and eigenvectors matrices in terms of variables to run the regression in Dynare. Would this procedure still work?

Comment: @HansEngler Hi, many thanks for the welcome and the information. I've found this answer and it seemed that substitution is acceptable. Does this work if I substitute just the expressions that repeat themselves? The process is taking days even after substitutions, so I'm running out of ideas what to do. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/199603/symbolic-resultant-too-slow-keeps-running